# What is the purpose of application-name and keywords in meta tag?

Tags: html

What is the purpose or need of the below tags?

```
<meta name="application-name" content="StackOverflow">
<meta name="keywords" content="questions, answers"> <!-- SEO tells keywords aren't given importance these days -->
```

Comment: _"Represents the name of the Web application that the page represents."_ [W3C - Meta Name](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/meta.name.html#meta.name-constraints)

Comment: @AdamAzad - That's something already obvious from the property name. He's asking for the final purpose. What is it useful for?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I agree with you, that's the missing element, but to be more clear, let's take Instagram site as an example, They can add `application-name` meta tag and set its content to Instagram or if you're using a CMD like WordPress you can use that as application-name, though it isn't that clear.

Comment: -1 because of 2-for-1 question.

Comment: It is not a 2-in-1 question. As we know, "author", "application-name", "description" and "keywords" are the most used meta tags (at least during learning). Now it is obvious that "author" is a only a place holder, and "description" is very much needed for SEO, but the rest two are being obsolete. Hence was the question.

Answer (score 19):

According to HTML5 LC, a `meta` tag with [`name=application-name`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names) shall have value (in the `content` attribute) that is “short free-form string giving the name of the Web application that the page represents”; if the page is not an application, such a tag must not be used. Browsers “may use the application name in UI in preference to the page's `title`, since the title might include status messages and the like relevant to the status of the page at a particular moment in time instead of just being the name of the application.”

A `meta` tag with `name=keywords` specifies “a set of comma-separated tokens, each of which is a keyword relevant to the page”. It is normally ignored by search engines these days (and has never had an impact on browsers, as you can read between lines from the following note in HTML5 LC: “Many search engines do not consider such keywords, because this feature has historically been used unreliably and even misleadingly as a way to spam search engine results in a way that is not helpful for users.”

Answer (score 3):

From [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_name.asp):

- **application-name:** Specifies the name of the Web application that the page represents
- **keywords**: Specifies a comma-separated list of keywords - relevant to the page (Informs search engines what the page is about).

Comment: But whether the "application-name" is just like "author" or does it have a use (something like it will be given higher preference if used, over <title>)? Also are keywords being considered obsolete or still a good practice to use?

Comment: No, author specifies the author of the document, the application-name specifies the name of the application that the page represents.  They are not the same.  In regards to keyword meta, Matt Cutts himself has said they do not form part of the ranking algorithm (http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html)  Focus instead on creating great content for your users.

Answer (score -1):

The text in these tags is not displayed, but parsable and tells the browsers (or other web services) specific information about the page. Simply, it “explains” the page so a browser can understand it.